# Storing access permissions for mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data structure type question that I don't really know the answer too. Essentially I have four permission controls (isSecret, canEdit, isActive and hasPage) that I need to store in a for a number of different tables.

I have two solutions in mind, but I'm not sure which is the best performance wise:

1. Store each permission as a separate row on each table. To me this seems to be the fastest way to access the data when querying, but because PHP will handle permissions 90% of the time, it seems inefficient.
2. Have a single *permissions* column where the permission name (sec,edt,act,has) is stored as a comma separated string. This gives me flexibly in the future to introduce new/different permissions, looks neat in my database and is easy to use in both PHP and mySQL (I can use the IN lookup for queries and explode the string and work with it as an array in PHP). This column would be a varchar of 40 characters, allowing to me store up to 10 different permissions (3 letters and a comma)

Option 2 was my preferred solution until I realised that the IN command might be resource intensive. I thought it might take a performance hit using an IN command on every row in my table trying to look for inactive pages to filter out. To solve this, I could just fetch every single row in my column, and then filter the rows out with PHP, but again, I'm not sure how effective this will be.

Ideally I think in my solution sub-columns would be the best solution (a main permissions column and under this 4 sub-columns for each of my permissions) that could then be queried easily (ie. where permission.canEdit = 1)

Results will eventually be cached using memcache (when I am able to figure out how to use it and an effective method for clearing it), but I don't want to have to rely on this.

Comment: You could store a column that is X bits long, and then use the [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), I found a decent tutorial/guide on how to use them for permissions [here](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/create-permissions-using-bitwise-operators-in-php/)

Comment: Have you looked at column type of ENUM for your Option 2? It stores values much more efficiently than a comma separated list, and you don't have to split or join.

Comment: @Supericy That works perfectly thanks! Just what I was after.

Comment: @RezaSanaie I wanted to be able to store multiple permissions though, so something could be visible and not editable, so in that case enum wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say SETs

Comment: @RezaSanaie Going my the documentation, that looks like a neat way of doing what Supericy described - and if it's less work for me, then I might as well use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Garion in fact that's how mysql stores these values in the background for SETs, each value gets associated with a bit, so it already does the work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [SETs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) would be what you need